# Rollback for Atomic and Durability

Tags: sql, sqlite, acid

I am trying to understand the ACID property of database transction: how they are achieved; which part is atomicity and which part is durability ,etc.

Let's say I have a transction with two actions,`A` and `B`. Unfortunately, system powered off when performing `action B`. After a system reset, we know the database will preserve (through the rollback jounery in sqlite) the state before performing `action A`. So, which ACID property does this show, atomicity or durability?

Another case :Suppose when performing `action B` , an error happened and was notified to the applicaiton , and the application rollback. I consider this is as pure atomicity which is achieved by the user but not by the database engine. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples highlight atomicity: either both A and B are committed, or neither.

Durability is a property that comes into the picture only *after* the transaction is committed. The application can rest assured that if the COMMIT call succeeded, then is durable. A system reset or a power off will not revert the effect of a committed transaction, hence its durability.